# Trying to integrate $\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x^{1/3}\ln x}{x^2+4}\; dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, branch-cuts

This is a problem from a previous complex analysis qualifying exam that I'm working through to study for my own upcoming exam. I'm struggling with this combination of a fractional exponent and logarithm. Below is my attempt, but I need help with how to finish it or if there's a better method for this type of problem.

**Problem:**

Evaluate the improper integral:
$$
I = \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x^{1/3}\ln x}{x^2+4}\; dx
$$

Explain all steps carefully (show contours, introduce branches, etc.).

**Attempted Solution:**

Let $f(z) = \frac{z^{1/3}\ln z}{z^2+4}$ and consider the following contour with a branch cut along the positive real axis, where $\Gamma$ is the entire closed curve, $C_R$ is the outside circle of radius $R$, $C_r$ is the inside circle of radius $r$, $A$ is the line from $r$ to $R$, $B$ is the line from $R$ back to $r$, and $0\leq \arg z \leq 2\pi$.

[image: Contour]

Using the Residue Theorem, we have
$$
\begin{split}
\oint_\Gamma f(z) dz
 &= 2\pi i \Big(\text{Res}(f,2i)+\text{Res}(f,-2i)\Big) \\
 &= \int_{C_R} f(z)dz + \int_{C_r} f(z)dz
  + \int_r^R f(z)dz + \int_R^r f(z)dz,
\end{split}
$$
where $\int_r^R f(z)dz$ uses $\arg z = 0$ and $\int_R^r f(z)dz$ uses $\arg z = 2\pi$.

Note that $z^{1/3} = e^{\frac{1}{3}(\ln z)} = e^{\frac{1}{3}(\ln |z|+i\arg z)}$, thus we can write
$$
f(z) = \frac{e^{\frac{1}{3}(\ln |z|+i\arg z)}\Big(\ln|z|+i\arg z\Big)}{z^2+4}.
$$

Using the ML estimation lemma, we find that $\int_{C_r} f(z)dz$ goes to zero as $r\to 0$ and $\int_{C_R}$ goes to zero as $R\to\infty$. (Work omitted here but can be shown if needed.) We're left with
$$
\begin{align*}
2\pi i \Big(&\text{Res}(f,2i)+\text{Res}(f,-2i)\Big) \\
&= \int_r^R f(z)dz + \int_R^r f(z)dz\\
&= \int_r^R \frac{e^{\frac{1}{3}(\ln |z|)}\ln|z|}{z^2+4}dz + \int_R^r \frac{e^{\frac{1}{3}(\ln |z|+2\pi i)}\Big(\ln|z|+2\pi i\Big)}{z^2+4}dz\\
&= \int_r^R \frac{x^{1/3}\ln x}{x^2+4}dx - e^{\frac{2\pi}{3}i} \int_r^R \frac{x^{1/3}(\ln x+2\pi i)}{x^2+4} dx 
\end{align*}
$$

Now from here, I know how to evaluate the residues and I see that we can isolate the term we're looking for as
$$
\lim_{r\to 0}\lim_{R\to\infty} \int_r^R \frac{x^{1/3}\ln x}{x^2+4}dx,
$$

but I don't know what to do with the remaining integral term on the righthand side. How do I complete this? Or should I have used a different contour or branch cut?

Comment: The second integral is also following the real axis, so $z$ can be replaced with $x$ in it, too.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Yes, I just wasn't yet sure if it helps me to do that at this step... I went ahead and changed that just in case it does.

Comment: Hint:$$\begin{align}\oint_\Gamma\frac{z^{1/3}dz}{z^2+4}&=(1-e^{2i\pi/3})\int_0^\infty\frac{z^{1/3}}{z^2+4}dz,\\\oint_\Gamma\frac{z^{1/3}\ln zdz}{z^2+4}&=\int_0^\infty\frac{z^{1/3}\ln z-e^{2i\pi/3}z^{1/3}(\ln z+2i\pi)}{z^2+4}dz\\&=(1-e^{2i\pi/3})\int_0^\infty\frac{z^{1/3}\ln z}{z^2+4}dz-2i\pi e^{2i\pi/3}\int_0^\infty\frac{z^{1/3}}{z^2+4}dz.\end{align}$$To evaluate the contour integrals, use the fact that, since phases increase from $0$ to $2\pi$ around $\Gamma$,$$(2i)^{1/3}=\sqrt[3]{2}e^{i\pi/6},\,(-2i)^{1/3}=\sqrt[3]{2}i,\,\ln(2i)=\ln2+\frac{i\pi}{2},\,\ln(-2i)=\ln2+\frac{3i\pi}{2}.$$

Comment: Having said that, I would recommend evaluating $\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{s-1}dx}{x^2+4}$ by taking $z=\frac14x^2$ before you use a keyhole contour, as you then only have one pole to worry about, $z=-1$. Then you can take the $s$-derivative at $s=\frac43$.

Comment: wouldn't it be simpler with $9\int \frac{x^3\ln(x)}{x^6+4}dx$ ?

Comment: @zwim That's a _lot_ of poles. Besides, what if the $x$ exponent were irrational?

Comment: @J.G. Not as many poles as transforming to $2^{-5/3}\int_{-\infty}^\infty (u+\ln 2)e^{u/3}\operatorname{sech} u\,du$. But hey, no more branch cuts.

Comment: I was genuinely asking, I'm not familiar at all with residues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your choice of branch cut is fine.  Note that for $0<\alpha<2$, we have

$$\frac{d}{d\alpha}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^\alpha}{x^2+4}\,dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^\alpha \log(x)}{x^2+4}\,dx$$

So, all we need to do is evaluate the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^\alpha}{x^2+4}\,dx$, differentiate with respect to $\alpha$, and set $\alpha=1/3$.

Proceeding, we use the same methodology, which after letting $r\to 0$ and $R\to \infty$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{r\to 0^+}\lim_{R\to \infty}\oint_C \frac{z^\alpha}{z^2+4}\,dz&=(1-e^{i2\pi\alpha})\int_{0}^\infty \frac{x^\alpha}{x^2+4}\,dx\\\\
&=2\pi i \left(\frac{2^\alpha e^{i\pi \alpha/2}}{4i}+\frac{2^\alpha e^{i3\pi \alpha/2}}{-4i}\right)\\\\
&=-\pi i 2^\alpha e^{i\pi \alpha}\sin(\pi\alpha/2)
\end{align}$$

Therefore we find that

$$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{x^\alpha}{x^2+4}\,dx=\pi 2^{\alpha-2}\sec{\pi \alpha/2} $$

Differentiating and setting $\alpha =1/3$ yields

$$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{x^{1/3} \log(x)}{x^2+4}\,dx=2^{-2/3}\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}+\frac{\pi \log(2)}{\sqrt 3}\right)$$

Comment: This answer was incredibly helpful! That trick with the integral at the beginning (Feynman's technique?) is new to me and hopefully I can learn to recognize when I can use it like this... Definitely made the problem simpler.

Comment: I'm pleased to hear!  It was my pleasure helping.

Comment: Would the anonymous downvoter care to comment as to why this was not useful?  I suspect that this is a personal attack since neither of the other posted solutions were down voted!!

Answer (score 4):

$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^a}{x^2+4}dx$$ Let $x=2\sqrt{t}$

$$I=2^{a-2}\int_0^\infty \frac{t^{\frac{a-1}{2}}}{t+1}dt=2^{a-2}\text{B}(\frac{a+1}{2},\frac{1-a}{2})=2^{a-2}\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi\frac{a+1}{2})}=2^{a-2}\frac{\pi}{\cos(\pi\frac{a}{2})}$$

Your integral is the following.
$$\left(\frac{d}{da}I\right)_{a=\frac{1}3}$$

Comment: I thought the OP was looking for a solution using complex analysis, not real analysis.  See that Tags:  Complex Analysis, Contour Integration, and Branch Cuts.

Comment: "or if there's a better method for this type of problem", so he asks for a better method @MarkViola

Comment: The OP staes up front "This is a problem from a previous complex analysis qualifying exam ..."  So, real analysis methods are not applicable.  And the microphone drops ...Aside, how do you quantify "better" here?  Your real analysis method is different.  How is it "better?"

Comment: you have to ask the author, he wrote for better, it depends on him how he defines "better". For my understand, it is quicker and can be used to get $\ln^k(x)$ case.

Comment: Again, it's made very apparent that the OP is seeking a solution using complex analysis to prepare for an upcoming exam in that subject area.  All tags relate to this.  All of the OP's analysis uses complex analysis and contour integration.  All currently posted comments under the question relate to complex analysis.  Of course this can be solved using real analysis.  That was not the point of the posted question.

Comment: MathFail: Thanks for your method! @Mark Viola is correct that I was looking for the best possible (meaning simplest, most straightforward, and quickest) method within the framework of complex analysis. The qualifying exam I'm studying for will be testing knowledge in this area - not just correct answers, but demonstrated competence specifically in complex analysis methods. THAT SAID, I still find the method you provided interesting and useful to note.

Comment: What is the notation $B(\cdot,\cdot)$ used in your answer?

Comment: beta function,.

Answer (score 2):

Your method will certainly work, though some of the other posted methods are likely cleaner. Continuing (roughly) from where you left off, we have
$$
2\pi i \left[\operatorname{Res}(f,2i)+\operatorname{Res}(f,-2i)\right] = \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{1/3}\ln x}{x^2+4}dx - e^{\frac{2\pi}{3}i} \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{1/3}(\ln x+2\pi i)}{x^2+4} dx.
$$
First, the RHS. We can then refactor the integrals to get the rather simpler
$$
\sqrt{3}e^{-i\pi/6}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{1/3}\ln x}{x^2+4}dx + 2\pi e^{i\pi/6}\int_{0}^\infty \frac{x^{1/3}}{x^2 + 4}dx.
$$
Next, the LHS. We know that $\operatorname{Res}(f, a) = a^{1/3}\ln a / (2a)$. However, there's a subtle point: when evaluating the numerator, we must remember the branch of $\ln$ that we've chosen. $2i = 2e^{i\pi/2}$ as usual, but here we must use $-2i = 2e^{3\pi i/2}$, not $-2i = 2 e^{-i\pi/2}$. Doing the (somewhat messy) calculation then gives
$$
2\pi i \left[\frac{2^{1/3}e^{i\pi/6}(\ln 2 + i\pi/2)}{4e^{i\pi/2}}+\frac{2^{1/3}e^{i\pi/2}(\ln 2 + 3i\pi/2)}{4e^{3i\pi/2}}\right] =\frac{\pi}{2^{2/3}}\left[e^{-i\pi/6}\left(\ln 2 + \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}\right) + e^{i\pi/6}\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{3}}\right].
$$

Finally, since $e^{-i\pi/6}$ and $e^{i\pi/6}$ are linearly independent over the reals, we can just equate their coefficients to get
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{3}x^{1/3}\ln x}{x^2+4}dx = \frac{\pi}{2^{2/3}\sqrt{3}}\left(\ln 2 + \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}\right) = \frac{\pi}{2^{2/3}}\left(\frac{\pi}{6} + \frac{\ln2}{\sqrt{3}}\right).
$$
And, as a bonus,
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{1/3}}{x^2+4}dx = \frac{\pi}{2^{2/3}\sqrt{3}}.
$$